# Display the output below using string dunder?

Tags: python-3.x, class

I am trying to display all the items in the expenditures list belonging to the same category then followed by the total of each category and lastly, the overall total. For example:

```
$12.00 Mon, 12 Aug 2019 Food
$15.25 Mon, 12 Aug 2019 Food
Total for Food = $27.25
$8.40 Wed, 14 Aug 2019 Drinks
Total for Drinks = $8.40
$33.00 Tue, 13 Aug 2019 Entertainment
Total for Entertainment = $33.00
Overall Total = $178.55
```

This is my code thus far. What I am trying to do is put all the items from the category into a dictionary with all the details and another where it is just the amount so I can sum it up.

```
class ExpenditureList:
    _types = ['Food','Entertainment', 'Drinks']
    def __init__(self):
        self._expenditures = []

    @classmethod
    def ExpenditureTypes(cls):
        return cls._types

    def __str__(self):
        exp = {}
        amount = {}
        temp = None
        for types in ExpenditureList._types:
            exp[types] = []
            amount[types] = []
        for item in self._expenditures:
            if item._type == ExpenditureList._types[0]:
                exp[item._type].append(item)
                amount[item._type].append(item._amount)
            elif item._type == ExpenditureList._types[1]:
                exp[item._type].append(item)
                amount[item._type].append(item._amount)
            elif item._type == ExpenditureList._types[2]:
                exp[item._type].append(item)
                amount[item._type].append(item._amount)
```

This is as far as I have gone and I'm not sure how do I return to get the above output